# css styles for tabbed menu, background color

Tags: css, menu, background, opacity

I wanted to add a tabbed look to the website i am building. Already did that, but now i want to change the tab color depending on which tab i am, which was also no problem, ecept for the color.

It seems that the code also uses the default background color of the menu.

My menu is contained within:

```
#container #menu ul li {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
float: left;
position: relative;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

I build a class .onlink to determine which page i am, and use this to display the correct color:

```
#container #menu ul li a.onlink{
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
color:#000;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
#container #menu ul li a.onlink:hover{
background: rgba(255, 255, 255,0);
}
```

When i hover over the menu bar, the color is correct, but when not hovering over it, the color is slightly off (gray), and seems to be a an articaft of the #container #menu ul li id.

Any suggestions on how to get the color of not hovering adjusted?

Comment: You should add a jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it (though I'm not entirely sure), it seems you want to have a transparent background-color, rather than a partially-transparent white background-color; that being the case then:

```
#container #menu ul li a.onlink {
    background-color: transparent;
    color:#000;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
#container #menu ul li a.onlink:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

The above, of course, means there is no difference in `background-color`  between the hovered, and non-hovered, states, so the `:hover` rule (the second) could be entirely omitted from the stylesheet (assuming that `background-color` is the only property contained within that selector), to give only:

```
#container #menu ul li a.onlink {
    background-color: transparent;
    color:#000;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

Of course, you could retain the `rgba()` colour notation, and simply keep the alpha (the fourth of the four numbers (the others being red, green and blue respectively) at `0` (fully-transparent), instead of `0.9` (90% opaque/almost entirely visible)):

```
#container #menu ul li a.onlink{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    color:#000;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input; your comment on the :hover set me on the right track.
I actually added the class onlink also to the list:
    #container #menu up li.onlink{
    background: rgba (255,255,255, 0.9)
    }

Answer (score 0):

try removing: `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input; your comment on the :hover set me on the right track. because the :hover line defines the background color. In my code i only defined the background color of the function , not of the block.

I actually added the class .onlink also to the list:

```
#container #menu up li.onlink{ 
background: rgba (255,255,255, 0.9) 
}
```

This resulted in a correctly displayed effect.
Thanks for the suggestions.